# youtube - embed interactive transcript feature

Tags: youtube, embed, closed-captions

Youtube has the new interactive transcript feature that is pretty amazing.  SEO value, increased usability etc.  So naturally I wanted to embed it on my site as well.  For the life of me, I can't find a way.

I'm using the iframe and javascript api, and couldn't find anything.  When I scoured the entire api, the only thing I could find was some  [gData api Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions.html#Upload_Transcript) related to closed captions. But I don't believe it enables a way to embed the interactive transcripts.

Is there a way?  Any idea if it'll come anytime soon?

If not, [Speakertext Captionbox](http://speakertext.com/captionbox) is the best free, open source 3rd party solution.  But it still lacks google's auto transcribe feature, and it's not exactly the all in one package for convenience I was hoping for.

Thanks all!

Comment: BTW, SpeakerText is not free now. http://speakertext.com/pricing